# Magento 2 Default RSS Generator only part of products

Tags: rss, magento2

I am using Magento 2 Community 2.1.9, I am also set the default RSS feeds. I reviewed the content of the XML generated, it shows only some of the eligible products.

For example, I set to generate XML for a category of 'shoes', only some of the shoes inside this category are included in the XML. Most are not included.

I am confused, do you have any idea? Is there a bug? How I can modify the code to make it include everything under the said category.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the products are visible/in stock/enable

Also compare any one of the product that is not seen in the feed with the product that is seen to check all the attribute values are set properly.

Hope this helps